# How to use current div width/height as minimum width/height?

Tags: javascript, css, html

How can I use the current width/height (which are both specified in percentage 100%) as the minimum width/height?

Here is a try:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Layout</title>
        <script>
            var myDiv = document.body;
            var curWidth = myDiv.style.width;
            var curHeight = myDiv.style.height;
            myDiv.style.minWidth = curWidth;
            myDiv.style.minHeight = curHeight;

            myDiv = document.getElementById('wrapper1');
            var curWidth = myDiv.style.width;
            var curHeight = myDiv.style.height;
            myDiv.style.minWidth = curWidth;
            myDiv.style.minHeight = curHeight;
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            html {
                height: 100%;
            }
            body {
                height: 100%;
            }
            #wrapper1 {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
            #wrapper2 {
                width: 8%;
                height: 100%;
                float: left;
            }
            #wrapper3 {
                width: 92%;
                height: 100%;
                float: left;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper1">
            <div id="wrapper2">
                Wrapper
            </div>
            <div id="wrapper3">
                Wrapper
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Trying to set min width/height of all divs to be the current width/height (which are both 100% by css) using Javascript (or using only css if possible)

Comment: Ok I'm confused. You want your width to be set as your min-width? Why not just forget the min-width/min-height and set the height and width as those directly?

Comment: No he wants all divs on the page to be the same height in px as they are in %. He want's the rest of the div's to conform to the px based upon their change due to view-port size or window size. For what purpose, I don't know but from looking at what he has done it looks like he knows what he is doing.

Comment: I am trying to make my page fill the whole browser window at first (100% width/height) and have the behaviour of a fixed (not fluid) page when the window is resized or when the user zooms in/out

Answer (score 2):

Be aware of the fact that `myDiv.style.height` does not return the height of an element if that was set through CSS, but only if the div looked something like `<div style="height: 10px"></div>`. You should use:

```
var curHeight = myDiv.offsetHeight;
var curWidth = myDiv.offsetWidth;
```

Edit: Oh, and you need to move your script tag at the end of your html, or you won't be able to select wrapper1 (or in a different file?).

Here is references on offsetHeight and offsetWidth. [Here](http://help.dottoro.com/ljuxqbfx.php)

That is the only problem I see with your approach assuming you do a document.write to insert the retrieved css values.

Comment: No, i'm not trying to use document.insert. I want my page to fill the whole browser window using 100% width/height and then snap as it is, which should prevent the divs from shrinking when the user makes the window smaller. Thats why I'm trying to set the minimum width/height to the size of the divs after assigning it to 100%

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, If you dont specify the width and height of a div by default it will always take it from its enclosing div.
example:

```
<body>
        <div id="wrapper1">
            <div id="wrapper2">
                Wrapper
            </div>
            <div id="wrapper3">
                Wrapper
            </div>
        </div>
</body>

<style>
         #wrapper1 {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
</style>
```

This will apply width and height both as 100% to all 3 divs in wrapper1, wrapper2, wrapper3